# Already uptodate in git - GIT PULL works but not GIT FETCH

Tags: git

I have some committed changes in local repository. Now I FETCH the remote repository and MERGE it..It says "Already Uptodate" but its not. I checked the logs and file and its not uptodate.

When I do a PULL it automatically merges the latest changes correctly without any problem and creates a new commit. Also, was able to push the changes successfully.

Questions.

1. Why there is a problem only with my FETCH/MERGE. Why it does not pull the changes..How do I pull the latest changes and commit it and push it, so no commits are lost?
2. If PULL is FETCH/MERGE, why it works differently in this case?

cOMMANDS USED:

```
GIT FETCH "URL"
GIT MERGE MASTER

For PULL

GIT PULL "URL"
```

Comment: On which branch are you? And what commands are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `git pull` without specifying the branch it pulls the branches it is tracking.

To check which branches you are tracking for a given remote check by running something like this which will produce something like this :

```
$ git remote show origin
…
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
develop merges with remote develop
master  merges with remote master
```

In order to set this up I believe all you have to do is add the `-u` or `--set-upstream` argument with your next `git push`.

Answer (score 2):

After your `fetch` you want to merge the content of your remote tracking branch e.g. `origin/master`, not your own current branch.

Comment: Its a type on my commands used section...I tried origin/master but still same problemmm